# Laravel 5 shared host subdomain htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5, subdomain

Firstly because im on a shared host I cannot place contents of my public folder directly into root. I have to place the entire project into the public_html directory and use a .htaccess to point to the public folder like below (which works fine for a single Laravel project):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

I now created a subdomain with the host and it created a directory inside my public_html directory called store.domain.com. This will be for an entirely different Laravel project. If I place the regular folder structure with the .htaccess file into this subdomain folder I get a 503 error when accessing the subdomain. I spoke to the host and when they suggested removing the root .htaccess file the subdomain started working but the main domain fell over.

Ive been struggling for days now reading up various solutions to other peoples similar issues on WordPress but cannot get anything to work correctly. The solution below sort-of works but it keeps adding on the public folder to my URL for the subdomain (root domain project is working fine):

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^store.mc.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^store.mc.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

Anyone had this issue or know how to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont really understand why this works but the below fixed my issue:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/ [L]
```

Comment: Yes added these rewrite rules to .htaccess

Comment: Helpful, when I created .htaccess in root

Answer (score 1):

I uploaded my website files to a subdomain, and I always see this error

> You don't have permission to access this resource. Additionally, a 403
> Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Just create a file `.htaccess`  In the subdomain folder

Add this to it and save .

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteCond is invalid without the leading slash.

change :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
```

Comment: I would think without the slash it would be relative to .htaccess location but even then the first code block is not the problem and as you can see with the second block the / is there.